# Smoothly colouring a toroid

Tags: general-topology, coloring

If you discretise the surface of a toroid into facets, what is the best way to colour each facet with unique colours without discontinuities across a continuous colour palette?

I'm trying to colour each node of a Self Organising Map (toroid topology) in a way that keeps each node uniquely identifiable, but also retains the layout of the SOM nodes.

If you un-fold the toroid into a rectangle, the four corners should be similar in colour, the top and bottom should reflect each other, and the same with the sides.

My approach was to define some control points along the edges that satisfy these conditions, as well as a few extra points within the rectangle. I then interpolated the red/green/blue values onto a regular grid, [giving this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WlQb.png).

Is there a better approach to the problem of colouring a toroid? Preferably an analytic solution? Any pointers would be great.

Comment: Topologizing the color space is an old problem of humanity. There are dozens of proposals by masters and laymen alike, but there is no accepted standard solution. Before one can go into the fine structure of the toroidal mesh you would have to make public your  global idea of mapping the color space onto the torus.